# adding jquery in masterpage

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery its loading it, but its not working.
when I check the firebug console, I dont c any error, but in IE developer console.

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'addEventListener'  jquery.js, line 4 character 6105

{ i.e version of jquery :http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js }

I am wondering why????
do you have any idea or I am missing some thing?

by the way here is the Script Registration code.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptLink1" runat="server" Name="jquery.js" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="false" />
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: jquery.js is your custom javascript file right? Do you referred default javascript file before referring your custom javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everything in SharePoint I would use jQuery versions 1.x, the latest being 1.10 as of today I think. This because of it's greater support for older browsers:

> jQuery 2.0 is intended for the modern web; we’ve got jQuery 1.x to
>   handle older browsers and fully expect to support it for several more
>   years. If you want, you can serve 2.0 to newer browsers and 1.9 to
>   older ones using our conditional comment trick, but that is not
>   required. The simplest way to support older browsers is to use jQuery
>   1.x on your site, since it works for all browsers.

Source [jQuery](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)

So, download and install 1.10, and it should work like a charm

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it working great....
now facing the other bug, might you have idea as well for this, in my style 

$(function(){
  // code here 
});
-----------------------------------
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code here
});

both are not working....
in IE console prompt following error.

SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object 
style.js, line 1 character 1

Comment: Great! The second problem can be due to SP 2010 internal variables named $, so use jQuery instead of $ for 2010